# prime factorization decryption

Tags: java, encryption, prime-factoring

I have a program that is supposed to decrypt a number to its primes. The primes also have an order: for instance, 2 is the 1st prime number, 3 is the second 5 is the third and so on. The indexes are 1 is for a, two is for b, three is for c and so on. I don't know how to compare the two array lists in order to assign an index to each prime so I can decode a word which is encrypted in the number 72216017. The number 72216017 has the primes 17,19,47,67,71. If 2,3,5,7,11... are a,b,c,d,e... these five prime numbers make up the word ghost, I just don't know how to assign and sort these numbers by their index.

```
package name;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimeFactorsEffective {
    private static int z;
    private int w = z;

    public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int numbers) {
        int n = numbers;
        List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
            while (n % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                n /= i;
            }
            if (n > 1) {
                factors.add(n);
                System.out.println(factors);
                z = Collections.max(factors);
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Primefactors of 72216017");
        for (Integer integer : primeFactors(72216017)) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
        List<Integer> factors1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> index1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i;
        int element = 0;
        int num = 0;
        int maxCheck = z; // maxCheck limit till which you want to find prime numbers
        boolean isPrime = true;
        String primeNumbersFound = "";


        //Start loop 1 to maxCheck
        for (i = 1; i <= maxCheck; i++) {
            isPrime = CheckPrime(i);
            if (isPrime) {
                primeNumbersFound = primeNumbersFound + i + " ";
                factors1.add(i);
                factors1.get(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + maxCheck + " are:");
        System.out.println(factors1);
    }

    public static boolean CheckPrime(int numberToCheck) {
        int remainder;
        for (int i = 2; i <= numberToCheck / 2; i++) {
            remainder = numberToCheck % i;
            if (remainder == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with « so I can decode my wors » ?

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. The number 72216017 has the primes 17,19,47,67,71. If 2,3,5,7,11... are a,b,c,d,e... these five prime numbers make up the word ghost. I just don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: How is the order of the primes defined? I guess the ordering should be increasing. Am I right?

Comment: The order is increasing.

Comment: If the answer(s) here helped you please accept one of them. This has a number of benefits for you, for the answerers and for other users of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Your answer did provide me with ideas of how to continue, however, I'm new to coding and I am experiencing trouble understanding it. For instance, I am not sure how to include the binarySearch, and I am looking up for ways to understand how does it work. In addition, I had the ArrayList set already, but why List is better? Anyway, you did provide me with some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the primes in a `List` (primes in this list will be in increasing order). Now you can use `Collections.BinarySearch` to get the index of the prime for which you wan to find the corresponding alphabet. Once you got the index (index here according to you starts from 1, so `a`'s index is 1, `b`'s index is 2, `c`'s index is 3 and so on) you can do simply something like `char currentCharacter = (char) ('a' + primeIndex - 1)` and the variable `currentCharacter` will store the alphabet corresponding to `primeIndex`.

Some other minor things that I'd like to suggest:

1. Which checking whether a number is prime or not, you can simply check upto square-root of `numberToCheck`. So you can replace your loop `for (int i = 2; i <= numberToCheck / 2; i++)` to `for (int i = 2; i*i <= numberToCheck; i++)`. Note that It is not a good idea to calculate square-root using `Math.sqrt`, instead you can have a condition like `i*i <= numberToCheck`.
2. Please refrain from naming your packages that seem to be random.
3. As of Java SE 7 explicit type-arguments while initializing the list are not required. You can replace `List<Integer> factors1 = new ArrayList<Integer>()` with `List<Integer> factors1 = new ArrayList<>()`. Please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) for more information.
4. Your factor method don't really look good to me, it don't give correct results. Please see the following method that gives correct result:

{{

```
public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int numbers) {
    int n = numbers;
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; n>1; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    z = Collections.max(factors);
    return factors;
}
```